# Resizing a JLabel with an setted Icon in a Panel when resizing the Window

Tags: java, swing, timer, resize, jlabel

I have a certain question about resizing an JLabel with a setted Icon.

My Solution was create a Timer which resizes the Label by invoking the actionperformed()-method of an ActionListener-Interface.

Is there any better solution?

```
package examples;

import images.MyImage;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class examples2 {

    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Image image = resizeImage(MyImage.IMAGE_BLUE_BLACKGROUND,
                    panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight());
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));

        }

    }

    private static ActionListener buttonhandler = new ButtonHandler();
    private static Timer timer = new Timer(100, buttonhandler);

    private static JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(resizeImage(
            MyImage.IMAGE_BLUE_BLACKGROUND, 1600, 100)));

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel text = new JLabel("Hakan Kiyar");

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        northPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        northPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10), BorderLayout.WEST);
        northPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10), BorderLayout.EAST);
        northPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        northPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        text.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);

        label.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        label.add(text);

        panel.add(label);

        frame.setSize(364, 300);

        timer.start();

    }

    public static Image resizeImage(Image oldImage, int width, int height) {

        Image newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();

        g.drawImage(oldImage, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();

        return newImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically resize the Icon by using Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) class.

It will resize the Icon to fill the space available to the label. You can configure the class to stretch the Icon to fill the entire space or to respect the width/height ratio as space is made available.